# Не могу получить данные из бд Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Не могу получить данные бд

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

TextView textView;
...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        textView.setText(value);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        // ...
    }
};
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Выдает ошибку

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.elvir.firedb, PID: 3187
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert
>   value of type java.util.HashMap to String at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzcg(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzb(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zza(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source) at
>   com.example.elvir.firedb.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:32)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajp.zza(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakp.zzcxi(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Что именно происходит не так? Если возникают ошибки, то где и какие? Если отображаются не те данные, то что ожидали получить и что получили?

Comment: прошу пересмотрите

Comment: @elik, выведите в логи dataSnapshot.toString() и посмотрите что вам приходит. Сейчас вы пытаетесь к строке привести не строку. У вас приходит, видимо, объект какой-то. И покажите как выглядят данные в БД.

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что не удалось преобразовать `HashMap` в `String`.

Comment: 10-17 07:37:11.514 3801-3801/com.example.elvir.firedb D/MainTagName: Value is: null

Comment: база данных пуста се прально лог работает

Comment: и даже больше пустое значине стаит на техт  но стоит мне чтото написать на базу данных то се

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так `String value = "" + dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);`